# How can I iterate over (system) properties in a thread safe manner?

Tags: java, concurrency, system-properties

The following piece starts throwing `ConcurrentModificationException` in my application (in the iterator):

```
final Map<?, ?> systemProperties = System.getProperties()
final Map<String, String> properties = (Map<String, String>) systemProperties

for (final Entry<String, String> entry : properties.entrySet()) { // exception here
    System.out.println(entry)
}
```

I am running a multi-threaded application, and unfortunately I do not have access to the code that is modifying the system properties (it could even be a third party library).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix that, we can take a *snapshot* of system property keys:

```
final Properties systemProperties = System.getProperties()
final Set<String> keys = systemProperties.stringPropertyNames()

for (final String key : keys) {
    System.out.println("key: " + key)
    final String value = systemProperties.getProperty(key)
    System.out.println("value: " + value) // value can be null!
}
```

Notice the `value` comment - while `stringPropertyNames` states `set of keys in this property list where the key and its corresponding value are strings`, the system property could have been changed in the meantime.

---

Why so much legwork?

System properties are an instance of `java.util.Properties`, and its methods `getProperty`, `setProperty` are thread-safe.

Unfortunately, Properties' entry set's iterator (which I had used in question) is not thread-safe:

> If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation, or through the setValue operation on a map entry returned by the iterator) the results of the iteration are undefined

So actually when I was iterating over that map, some system property was modified (= that entry said was modified), which caused CME to be thrown.

---

This q&a pair also applies to any generic `Properties` usage - just system properties make it trickier, with ability to access them directly with statics such as `java.lang.System.setProperty(String, String)` - so controlling all accesses (especially in shared code) gets harder.

Comment: Where did you find out the `setProperty()` and `getProperty()` are thread-safe?

Comment: `This class is thread-safe: multiple threads can share a single Properties object without the need for external synchronization`

Comment: If one dives into the stringPropertyNames method used here, you end up in the Enumerator implementation in Hashtable, which also can throw a ConcurrentModificationException. Why would this implementation be thread safe?

Comment: Let me fine tune that; the Enumerator implements two loop mechanisms. In this case it is not used as an iterator, so it wont throw a ConcurrentModificationException, but the actually used method 'nextElement' can throw a NoSuchElementException. Which basically also is a CME. However, the chance of this occurring is way smaller, but I do not think it really is thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your properties in a `ConcurrentHashMap` so that any of your compound actions such as iteration, navigation, check-and-act, etc.. will be thread-safe.
e.g.

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> props = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(
    (Map<String, String>)(Object)System.getProperties());

for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry: props.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Note that the iterators returned by the `ConcurrentHashMap` are **weekly consistent**, which means it may or may not reflect the changes to the collection after the construction of the iterator. If this is not what you wanted, you could use the `Collections.synchronizedMap()` instead, which pays some penalties in concurrency.

Comment: `new ConcurrentHashMap<>((...)System.getProperties())` can potentially throw - you are iterating over Properties' entry set then :(

Comment: I don’t think it will. Entry set value is String type so it is immutable. This is supposed to be threadsafe

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html